# IPv6 address with cidr `/128`

Tags: ipv6

Under Ubuntu 1604, connect a box to a socket on the wall (of the lab), the box get both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. IPv4 works fine, but IPv6 does not . I noticed that the global IPv6 address has a CIDR 128, something like:

`inet6 2404:f123:4:47:800::1234/128`

I am wondering whether or not the IPv6 address with CIDR 128 valid? and why?

Thanks!

PS: My question is more about the *size* of 128, i.e., is it too big? Since I am expecting some number less than 128 such as 64. As an analogy, my IPv4 address is 192.168.10.117/24 or 127.0.0.1/8 where the CIDR is not 32 but less than 32. I even encountered once a problem with /32 IPv4 address which does not working, after changing it to /24 it worked then.

Comment: See: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/49095/62771

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this in cases where the Router Advertisement advertises the subnet as "not on-link". The receiver therefore makes no assumptions about who is reachable on that subnet by creating a single /128 address and sending everything through the default gateway (which is usually a link-local address, so that will work).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes after checking a working configuration on Windows, I realized that my understanding of IPv6 was not correct. It seems that it's the link-local address (fe80:.../64) is used for direct communication with routers (and hosts on the subnet), not the global address (2404:.../128). This is different from IPv4. What's left for me is to check why it's not working on Ubuntu :)